# Rails: Foreign Keys and when to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, migration, relational-database

Three questions:
When you create a model, is a foreign_key automatically created as well?

I'm thinking I should add_index when a column is unique to the table or unique in general, or when the column will relate to other databases, Amirite?

What will an index look like? Will it just use the contents of the cell?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Do you mean when using a generator? Generally speaking, you should generate migrations, rather than use a generator for the whole model/scaffolding. And then, no, a foreign key is not automatically created, only if you specify it.

2) add_index is going to come in handy for columns on big tables that need to be accessed *quickly* by your database. Let's say you've got a `users` table with an `email` column that must be unique, but isn't indexed. And your service grows, now you have millions of users, and you need to go `User.find_by_email "someone@example.com"`. Without an index, that's going to take you a while. With an index, it'll be quick. That's when an index comes in handy.

3) Really depends on your database engine afaik. Not something that will affect your day-to-day imho (though if you have a specific database engine in mind, you can certainly find out). Here's the info on MySQL, straight from the source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html

Comment: So rails generate model, then write the migration, is better practice? Also I think I figured it out. So when I when I use the t.references method, I'm creating the foreign key?

Comment: no - you don't need to generate the model. Generate the migration, write the model. And `index: true` within the migration will mark a col as index, though you have ways to add index after the fact too.

Comment: sure thing, happy to help :)